# question regarding partitions of set by equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

I have a question regarding whether two sets are equal or not.

Basically I have a equivalence relation given by $x \sim y \in Q$ where $Q$ is the set of rationals.

I know that based on the above, there is a partition of the real numbers $R$ given by say [0],[$z_1$],[$z_2$],[$z_3$],.... where [0] is the set that contains all the rational number, [$z_1$] is a set that contains only irrational numbers and the numbers in the [$z_1$] set is all different from the number in the [$z_2$] set by an irrational number,.... so each [$z_i$] contains uncountably number of irrational numbers.

My question is regarding the following:

I was reading a proof that says

[0,1] $\subseteq \bigcup_{q \in Q \cap [-1,1]} (q+E) \subseteq [-1,2]$

where E is a set that contains just one element from each of the equivalence class defined above. 
So one element from [0], one from [$z_1$],one from [$z_2$],...

My question is how does the set [0,1] being contained in the union of (q+E) defined above? because I know that say if we pick a rational in [-1,1], say we pick 0.3, and say a rational 0.7 from the set [0], then I have 0.3 + 0.7 = 1 , so yes 1 is indeed contained in the set $\bigcup_{q \in Q \cap [-1,1]} (q+E) $, but how about 0? because I already use 0.7 from the set [0], is it still possible to have 0 in the set [0,1] to be in the set $\bigcup_{q \in Q \cap [-1,1]} (q+E) $?

because in the set E, you can only have one rational number, and already use that (in this case I use 0.7) to obtain 1, i.e. 0.3+0.7 =1, then how can we obtain 0 from the equation of   x +y = 0 , if y can no longer be rational, and x is a rational in the set Q $\cap [-1,1]$  ?

My question is does the set [0,1] actually a subset of the set  $\bigcup_{q \in Q \cap [-1,1]} (q+E) $? or there is a mistake in the notes?

this is the notes I was reading:

https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/MA2224/MA2224-ch2.pdf

the very last page of the pdf above.

Comment: I think you mean $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you are a little confused about something, but reading through your question, I'm not quite sure exactly what it is your confused about. I'll just try to explain as clearly as I can.

Ok, firstly, the answer. Yes,
$$[0,1]\subseteq \bigcup_{q\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]} (q+E).$$

Why?

Well, if $x\in [0,1]$, then $x\sim e$ for some $e\in E$, since $E$ contains one element in every equivalence class. Moreover,
since $e\in [0,1]$ as well, then $-1\le -e \le 0$, and $0\le x\le 1$, so
$-1\le x-e\le 1$. Thus $x-e$ is a rational (since $x\sim e$) in $[-1,1]$,
so $x\in (x-e)+E$. Hence every element of $[0,1]$ is in the union
$\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]} (q+E)$.
Thus, by definition
$$[0,1]\subseteq \bigcup_{q\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]} (q+E).$$

Comment: Hi jgon, thanks. I think you have prove it and so clear. My question is that when I used say q =0.3, E = 0.7, then I got 0.3+0.7 =1 so yes 1 is indeed in that union. But how about 0? how do I obtained 0 from q +e where e is an element of E based on the above if I have chosen an element from the set [0] (this contains all rational numbers), and we can only have one element from each of the equivalence class and I already have 0.7 picked from [0] to satisfy 1 = 0.3 + 0.7, to show 1 is in the union.

Comment: How about 0, is it possible to have 0 of [0,1] is in the union as well? i.e. 0 = q + e where q is a rational number, e is an element in E but e being irrational number. (because I already have picked an element 0.7 which is a rational number, and the set E can only have one rational number, the rest being irrational numbers).

Comment: Let say the question is: show that the number, 0 and 1 is indeed in the union above using specific numbers. Is it possible to do that? say 0 = $x_1$ + $y_1$, 1 = $x_2$ + $y_2$, and only one of the y from here can be rational (i.e. either $y_1$ or $y_2$, but not both), because E only contains one rational number and infinitely many irrational number, and $x_1, x_2$ being rationals numbers here.